# Multiple Social Media Presences For Different Audiences

Tags: communication, work-life-balance, social-media

I'm not a huge fan of social media, but it's nessessary to use it to communicate with people inside my businesses industry.

With that in mind, I opened up a Twitter account which will be run from a personal perspective - Tweeting about all sorts of things that are relevant to my industry ( music . fashion . tattoo culture . cars/motorbikes . horror . modelling . + ).

So lets call it `@My_Diary`.

I'm looking at my industry participants and the type of things I have to follow, and it's very apparent that a lot of them post things that you would class as Not Safe For Work (NSFW):

- Tattooists who've done more erotic art, or piercings in certain body areas
- Models who cross the line of glamour, fetish, erotic, or 18+
- Horror producers who do content that is 18+ in nature ( Violence / Gore / Nude Acresses / Sexual Scenes )

So my best bet here is to produce a NSFW version of my account (`@My_NSFW_Diary`), where I can retweet anything that's not suitable for a PG audience.

But, there's a difference in what you call NSFW in this case.

Graphic Horror and Erotic Tattoo Art is NSFW, but it's not the same as 18+ model content. The same as Fetish modelling is classed as being mature content, but again it's not the same as being Erotic/18+.

So is it really logical to have just 2 accounts? Should there be 3:

`@My_Diary - Anything for audiences of all ages`

`@My_Diary_NSFW - Horror / Violence / Gore / Language / Fetish / Erotic Art`

`@My_Diary_NSFW_2 - Nude Models / 18+`

A workable sollution at first glance, but in reality you're really following all accounts multiple times - Models who do Regular/Glamour `AND` Fetish `AND` Erotic/18+.

Also, consider that I may want to break my business apart slightly and focus on both SFW and NSFW in different ways. So having:

`@My_Diary - All content mentioned above`

`NSFW_Diary - Focusing solely on the different aspects of Fetish/18+ Models and erotic content - Of which there is a clear direct link to from my main business`

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: @Fattie - Why limit my businss? There are many photographers out there who do music/events/family + nude/boudour work. Not all `Adult` work is as black and white as it seems. Horror is 18+, as are some music videos!

Answer (score 9):

> Any advice on how to effectively run a social media account for business AND personal reasons?

No. Make one account for business (including relationships to potential business partners) and, if you want (you don't seem to), make another one for personal and family interests.

You can minimize the overlap by deciding every time you see interesting content: Is this related to my business? Then use the business account - if you only want to use the personal account at a minimum anyway, there's no need to maintain a "complete" profile that shows all your interests. You can restrict that one for simple communication with friends and family.

Answer (score 4):

It's not about only social media, it's applicable on almost any cases related to the distinction between official and personal aspects.

Rule of thumb: Do not mix (or risk of mixing up) your personal viewpoints with that of the business.

Two tips:

- Maintain separate accounts. Use the business account for **strictly** business purpose only (communication, promotion, following, subscribing etc.). Do not engage with anything that is not related to business.
- In your personal accounts, add a disclaimer somewhere that the comments / opinions are personal and not related to the organization your work for. Do not use it for any business communication.

Comment: Just look at how some politicians & celebrities get themselves in hot water...

Comment: Thanks, but as I've suggested in the post, almost anything is potentially business related, and therefore having a single business account crosses very family orientated posts with explicit posts. From a business angle I can simply set up multiple accounts to promote my work in various sectors (Posting only). This is more about keeping up with and communicating with anyone across the multiple areas in which I'm willing to do work.

Comment: @W.H. I really don't see how is that a problem. The way I rad it, you are trying to put a clean impression for both your business and personal profile. That's okay, you can be selective as I suggested. However, if you're in doubt about adding someone to your contacts because of the nature of the content they may post - hey, there's no solver bullet. You need to measure the pros and cons and take the call of adding them or leaving them out.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Consider that my personal account is my business account. It's not for sharing details about what I had for lunch, but for finding connections who I could create content for as a business. My business activities don't need to be shared, simply made aware of by specific people who I want to work with. I find that many professionals who advertise their profiles as being 18+ have more acceptance posting about everyday subjects than those who claim to be family orientated but occasionally want to make a comment on NSFW content. I kind of lie in the middle of the road with this one!

Comment: @W.H. - `Consider that my personal account is my business account.` isn;t that exactly the thing we're suggesting not to do?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You're reading too much into Personal. Consider a freelancer has a name, which is their business name.

Comment: That said, the posts by your contacts does not necessarily make you responsible for them, However from a business standpoint, I understand the need to keep the account professional - however, if you say your business has to deal with NSFW content - then they are not really categorized as NSFW - they are part of the work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - I've re-worded my post. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @W.H. If *almost anything is potentially business related* you have another issue: information overload.

Comment: @JanDoggen - Explain?