# Building a SFW business which must also contain NSFW participants

Tags: social-media, inappropriate-content

New Updated Question

I run a small business that primarily deals with UK sub-culture industries - Think Heavy Metal, Tattoos, Motorbikes, Gothic, etc.

Now I want to open up a Lifestyle blog where I can talk about my personal interests as well as using it as a tool for promoting business activities, and I plan on opening up a blog named something like `Diary of Rock`, and to run a Twitter account with the same branding (`@DiaryOfRock`).

The problem is that my industry crosses the line slightly into what you can class as Safe for Work (SFW) and what you can't (NSFW). And to make things worse, there are different classifications of NSFW. For example:

`1 - Violence / Light Nudity / Fetish / Graphic Horror`

`2 - Sexually Explicit Content / Erotica`

Does this mean I should break my accounts down into 3 classifications?

Any thoughts, or advice on how you deal with such problems?

--

Old Vesion

`I run a small business that primarily deals with UK sub-culture industries - Think Heavy Metal, Tattoos, Motorbikes, Gothic, etc. Now I want to open up a Lifestyle blog where I can talk about my personal interests as well as using it as a tool for promoting business activities. So I plan on opening up a blog named something like "Diary of Rock" and to run a Twitter account with the same branding (@DiaryOfRock). So I'm guessing that even though my personal twitter is @MyRealName, I'm probably likely to use my blog account as my primary account as it accounts for a big chunk of my interests and life. The problem I have is that my industry interests often cross a line between what you can class as Safe for Work (SFW) and what you can't (NSFW). So to overcome this, am obvious solution is: @DiaryofRock and @DiaryofRock_NSFW. The problem is the classification of NSFW. Take films - They can be rated R/18 for extreme violence but contain no sexual content, or can be rated R/18 for sexual content but have no violence. So does this mean you need to have: @DiaryofRock + @DiaryofRock_NSFW and @DiaryofRock_XXX. Disclosing in the description exactly what followers can expect from each account? Any advice?`

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/109726/75821

Comment: Not really @SolarMike - This is about Twitter, not at all about Facebook - I hate Facebook!

Comment: It is the "concepts" that are useful, not always the specific package in use, I thought you would "get" that.

Comment: Completely different privacy setting and friend listing capabilities on Facebook + Facebook only allows a single account that is your own full name, making participation in groups difficult if speaking from a business point of view.

Comment: Please don't edit your question so as to invalidate the existing answers. You can always ask a new question (and you did, but deleted it).

Comment: Yes @PhilipKendall, I asked a new question and was flagged because `it was a duplicate` of **this**. Judging by what you're saying, it's nothing like my original - So I'm at a complete loss.

Comment: Not only do I think that Joe is right, I also think that you're missing out on the most important social media of today: Instagram and Facebook.

Comment: @Jonast92 - I don't plan on only using Twitter, just using that as a primary base. Still the same question / problems is relevant whichever social network it's applied to. I have decided to split my blog into 2 or more sections, but not nessessarily with completely different business marketing. I've tried to post an updated version of my question to match my new plan, but it got closed for being the same as this, oddly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Social Media Presences For Different Audiences](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/135455/multiple-social-media-presences-for-different-audiences)

Comment: Not exactly @motosubatsu - This is really a new question, and the `Duplicate` is closed, so I can't edit that question

Comment: @W.H. With all due respect you might *think* this is a new question but really it's the same question you've been asking minor variations of both on here and on IPS for weeks.Essentially it always boils down to the same issue of how to keep SFW and NSFW content separate across multiple twitter accounts without making the process too onerous to yourself.

Comment: I appreciate it's a tricky problem - I really do but with all kindness I think you need to try a different avenue to try and get the information you're looking for because you keep getting the same result over and over again where you get an answer and then you argue with people that the aren't getting what you are asking. I don't think SE is the right format for this discussion.

Comment: @motosubatsu Surely there must be people on here who work in an industry that faces the same problem. I'm just looking for a few examples - or a working solution to the concept of brealing down the content to be placed on each account

Comment: @W.H. the thing is no matter how many times you've shaken that magic 8-ball the answer keeps coming up the same - you just don't seem to like it.

Comment: @motosubatsu - The answer is always to split it SFW & NSFW - I get that and will do that. But this is about the need to further break down the NSFW category. There feels a need to do that as some NSFW content is related to the SFW, and some is a little bit too adult related

Comment: @motosubatsu - Maybe better placed on Lifehacks, as it's about how to actually present yourself as a person with multiple interests, in multiple areas of life - But I don't feel like setting up on there just to have it marked as Off Topic!

Comment: The "answer" to that is still the same - split it SFW & NSFW, there's no one-size-fits-all rule that will let you do that, you have to use your judgement on a case by case basis. As you say "NSFW" encompasses a great deal of different areas but if it's "unsuitable for children or for perusal at work when your boss is watching" it's a pretty safe bet that it's "NSFW"

Comment: I don't claim to speak for Lifehacks but I'm 90% confident it wouldn't be a fit there either. As I've said to you before if you need help looking for a twitter (or whatever) client that can help you manage multiple accounts then *maybe* Software recs SE or Web apps SE.

Comment: @motosubatsu - I know that I'm going to use Tweetdeck using a private account for following/listing, and then add my other accounts for posting actual content. It's these other accounts that I can't get sorted. I know there's a main account, and I'd like a regular account ( things that are SFW but not related to my primary business - nature, sport, etc ), I also need a NSFW for things that are related to my business (fetish models who work associate with music/tattoo/etc), but feel I need a further NSFW account for more explicit content that may arise. Just looking for clarification really.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question about the *workplace*, other than that some of your proposed content isn't safe in one.  This sounds like a marketing or a business-planning question, and those aren't on-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because marketing (and also because opinion polls don't fit our format).

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Please vote to delete it!

Answer (score 19):

> So as I plan on opening a similar online business again, what's the
>   solution to a problem like this?

You should operate two completely separate businesses. That way you can completely segregate the two dissimilar groups of clients from each other.

Two websites. Two company names. Two email addresses. Two phone numbers. Perhaps even two mailing addresses.

Companies do this all the time.

Comment: It's not quite as simple as that. My business is really just a distribution platform for the written material - Like Universal Films produce/distribute hundreds of different films - I plan to distribute different promo materials for various events/professionals. So one business name is better - Split up into Categories on the website, and maybe multiple twitter accounts for promotion. My problem is more about making connections with lots of different people using a single universal account (`@WH_at_Business`). Check out the last paragraph!

Comment: @W.H. What was the last porn movie distributed under the banner of Universal Films?

Comment: @T.Sar - Who said anything at all about Porn? NSFW doesn't have to fall under the category of adult films - That's what makes this such a difficult situation!

Comment: @T.Sar - FYI - They distributed 50 Shades of Grey - Which many would class as Adult themed!!!

Comment: @W.H. That was just an extreme case for you to think about it. It isn't to be taken literally. However, there is a reason most shocking, extreme movies are usually independent or published by lower-profile studios.

Comment: @W.H. Fifty Shades didn't get an NC-17, so I wouldn't say it is an "adult" movie. Spicy, maybe. Lame? Absolutely. But not "adult".

Comment: @T.Sar - Never seen it so I can't comment - Adult rated or not - it's certainly adult themed.

Comment: Please check out my updated question - Hopfully it outlines why it has to be one business and not two.

Answer (score 2):

- You want your business to support NSFW clients.
- You want your business to support clients who would not be okay with you supporting NSFW clients.
- You want to manage things via social media.

You're going to have to open multiple accounts, one for each side.  When you get a NSFW client (through whatever means), you follow them with the NSFW account.  This is really the only way to achieve all of those objectives.  It may require some diplomacy, but I suspect that most of them will be okay with the idea that you have split accounts of that variety.  If they aren't?  Well, you can manage the above restrictions with some work.  If your NSFW clients are not okay with you having clients that are not okay with you having NSFW clients, though, something's going to have to give - you're going to have to give up one group or the other.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I feel that having 2 account for 'promotional' purposes isn't a problem at all, but on a personal level ( I hate social media but understand it's power and importance ) I'd prefer to use a single account for keeping in contact, rather than keep switching accounts to monitor what's going on. Effectively splitting your 8 hour day between 2 accounts seems like limiting both accounts to 4 hours. Also consider that I want to reduce my social activities to focus more on the actual work. Any thoughts?

Comment: @WH Figure out a script that will let you post to both accounts simultaneously, so that you can put the relatively clean stuff on both.  Past that, the issue is that social media is an accumulation of interactions, and hiding some of your interactions from some of your users is explicitly what you've said you want to do.  If you do that, then they will see fewer of your interactions.  That's pretty much inherent in the problem statement.  Note that this isn't foolproof.  You're still hiding things about yourself on the internet.  People *will* find out.  Hopefully not too badly.

Comment: @W.H. You can use TweetDeck to post to multiple accounts simultaneously, if you go in that direction.

Comment: Thanks @BSMP - I started to use TweetDeck and find it quite useful. However I still feel the need to use a universal account where I can follow & communicate with multiple people. I don't want to do all communication over multiple business accounts - Especially if they are not officially a client - If that makes sense.

Comment: @W.H. then you're going to have to accept that your customers are going to find out about each other, and the ones who are not cool with that will react accordingly.  If you're not willing to split accounts, and you want to use twitter, you don't have another option.

Comment: @BenBarden - Updated my question this morning - I'm going to split my accounts into several audiences - Just need to work out how to manage my time working on them all!

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to totally hide the fact you deal with NSFW business**, then you'll have to [run two businesses as Strazzere suggested](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/135536/100550). There's no other way.

---

Now, **if you just want to not forcefully broadcast the NSFW** portion of your business to your innocent SFW followers, **having two accounts that point to the same contact address works out**.

> That is necessary because even **Following/Liking NSFW content on Twitter can have it be automatically broadcasted to your followers**; it will simply show up on their feed sporadically (*next to their [daily prayers bot](https://twitter.com/positiveprayers) tweets nonetheless*).

I'm acquainted with tons of **freelance artists**, for instance, and most of them **separate their NSFW and SFW work accounts, but this is for their portfolio and their followers' sake**. There's no point in using a different business address for them, so they just have the same website/contact e-mail on the description of the 2 (or more) accounts. The accounts also link to each other in their own descriptions, so they are not "hidden"; however they are also not getting shoved down your potential clients' throats nor are they dividing your business attention.

Comment: Thanks. I'm certainly thinking about having 2 accounts which splits SFW/NSFW, but only having a link back to my SFW from the NSFW - Not the other way round as I don't think it's nessessary. This is only really for personal use anyway, but I would still like to be able to post things about my local town, as well as something more extreme. Only problem is that I plan on following a lot of Horror based content - Much of which is extremely NSFW, but not in the same sense as the Adult Performers. So I would still need to categorise my SFW profile as 18+ (???) - That complicates it further.

Comment: Can't have your cake and eat it too, I'm afraid. My pals have even gotten to the point they make a separate account just for their retweets/likes/text posts and one for their digital work where they just post because the followers like different things; that's really just the name of the game you're playing right now. The link loop is up to you, I'd recommend it so your NSFW clients don't feel intentionally secluded rather than just, well, given a special place.

Comment: Not sure if you would, but could you post a few twitter handles for freelancers who are doing this? I'd love to check out how they sepperate their work/timelines and how their websites relate to the content they post

Comment: I won't log into my Twitter right now for obvious reasons, but off the top of my head [@kinucakes](https://twitter.com/kinucakes) and [@vgc_scott](https://twitter.com/vgc_scott). They've kinda been doing their own thing though, and have the link to selling their naughty stuff pinned right on the front. You can be more subtle about it.

Comment: Thanks. I've bookmarked them to check out when I'm on Twitter later on. I've edited my post a little as it looks like I'll need 4 accounts.

Comment: @W.H. asking people to compromise their anonymity is not good... luckily they did not.

Comment: @SolarMike - WTF are you talking about?